# Create 1000 random 6-character strings that won't be interpreted as a number when imported to Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I need to create a list of 1000 unique random 6-character strings that are then exported in an automated process to Excel. The problem is that Excel drives stupid conclusions and interprets anything that vaguely might be a number as such, like 4587E7 becoming 4,59E+10 or omitting an initial 0 if the string does not contain any letter.

I wrote this nice SQL code that works perfectly, but that didn't took into account what Excel can ruin afterwards.

```
declare @i int = 0
WHILE @i < @Participants 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACCESSKEYS (UserID,InquiryID) Values (Substring(Replace(NEWID(),'-',''),4,6),@Inquiry)
    set @i = @i + 1
END

/*Security Loop to eliminate theoretical doubles*/

WHILE (Select Count(distinct(UserID)) from ACCESSKEYS where InquiryID = @Inquiry) < @Participants
BEGIN
    DELETE ACCESSKEYS
    Where ID in (Select ID
                 From (
                       Select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserID order by ID) as ord
                       From ACCESSKEYS
                       Where InquiryID = @Inquiry)x
                 Where x.ord = 2)

    INSERT INTO ACCESSKEYS (UserID,InquiryID) Values (Substring(Replace(NEWID(),'-',''),4,6),@Inquiry)
END
```

How can I make this Excel resistant? Without the obvious solution to place a static "X" in front of the string - which I will do I can't find a smarter solution.

---

What I finally came up with is this:

```
CHAR(Cast(RAND()*(91-65)+65 as int)) + Substring(Replace(NEWID(),'-',''),4,5)
```

I place a random letter in front of the portion coming from the GUID, using the CHAR Function that returns capital letters for the range from 65 to 90

Comment: Consider tweaking the process doing the exporting (or importing). If a string is entered as a formula (`="1e4"`), or the cell is explicitly formatted as text prior to inserting anything, Excel will leave it alone. Also note that the `NEWID()` manipulation you're doing here will not give a very good distribution of randomness, for cases where this matters, since the string representation of that contains only hexadecimal digits (so only A through F for letters).

Comment: Prefixing the value with a `'` should do the trick

Comment: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c7503c65734b6c9997006df36ae9ee37) is a little thing I cooked up that generates ids a little more effectively, and is made Excel-safe(r) by excluding `0` and `e` (still no logic for making sure numbers-only ids are not generated, but you could just leave those out entirely). Not polished enough for an answer.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `Count(distinct UserID)`, to make code clearer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Actually I'm not exporting but building a xls file dynamically in C# using the content from a asp:Gridview. Don't know where I could improve this 100% Excel related problem. Thanks for the comment on the relatively poor randomness, but I can live with the result or extend to 8 character long keys

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Should do the trick but doesn't. In order to process the data placed in the cell I need to doubleclick in each cell. Only then the ' disappears.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Great! I will do exactly what you proposed: Eliminating 0 and e first (and hoping that there isn't any other hidden Excel logic that intervenes on the remaining characters). The remaining 14 digits should do the job anyway!